# Load GUI Extension JS Files for 1 View

Tags: gui-extensions

I have a GUI Extension that loads an external javascript file and then integrates with the Tridion MessageCenter.  My problem is that the MessageCenter message is shown 2 times.  I believe my extension is enabled for 2 'views' and I need to somehow change the config to only load the JS files for the main dashboard view.

How could I do that?

Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge" xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters/>
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="MessageCenterSignalrGroup" >
          <cfg:domainmodel name="MessageCenterSignalrDomain">
            <cfg:fileset>
                <cfg:file type="script" id="rcJq">/js/jquery-1.6.4.js</cfg:file>
                <cfg:file type="script" id="rcSig">/js/jquery.signalR-1.1.1.js</cfg:file>
                <cfg:file type="script" id="rcNot">/js/notification.js</cfg:file>
            </cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:services />
          </cfg:domainmodel>
         <cfg:dependencies>
            <cfg:dependency/>
<!--            
            <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
                <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
    -->         
        </cfg:dependencies>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles/>
  <extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls/>
        <ext:listdefinitions/>
        <ext:taskbars/>
        <ext:commands/>
        <ext:commandextensions/>
        <ext:contextmenus />
        <ext:lists/>
        <ext:tabpages/>
        <ext:toolbars/>
        <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
  </extensions>
  <commands/>
  <contextmenus/>
  <localization/>
  <settings>
    <defaultpage/><!--/Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage>-->
    <navigatorurl/><!--/Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl>-->
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions/>
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path/><!--/CSS/</path>-->
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration/>
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

Javascript:

```
var connection = $j.connection('http://localhost/Signalr4TridionMC/messageCenter');

connection.received(function (data) {
    $messages.registerNotification(data);
});

connection.start();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having worked on this together, I know I have shared this with you before, but I have a different type of config to specify the view - here is a snippet from the config - its the bit with the `<cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Dashboard">` that specifies the view

```xml
<resources cache="true">
  <cfg:extensiongroups>
    <cfg:extensiongroup name="Message.Group">
      <cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Dashboard">
        <cfg:insertafter>Message.Resources</cfg:insertafter>
      </cfg:extension>
    </cfg:extensiongroup>
  </cfg:extensiongroups>
  <cfg:groups>
    <cfg:group name="Message.Resources">
      <cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:file type="script">js/jquery.js</cfg:file>
        <cfg:file type="script">js/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js</cfg:file>
        <cfg:file type="script">js/notification.js</cfg:file>
      </cfg:fileset>
    </cfg:group>
  </cfg:groups>
</resources>
```